# Unable to add init script to Mongo in Testcontainers

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, testcontainers

Trying to create some integration tests using testcontainers:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class InitInTcApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(InitInTcApplication.class, args);
}

@Service
static class FilterService {
    private final MongoClient mc;

    public FilterService(MongoClient mc) {
        this.mc = mc;
    }

    public List<Document> getDashboardContainingOldModel() {
        MongoCollection<Document> coll = mc.getDatabase("qDashboards")
                .getCollection("Dashboard");
        Bson hiddenFilter = Filters.exists("hidden", false);
        return coll.find(or(hiddenFilter)).into(new ArrayList<>());
    }
}

@Configuration
static class MongoConfig{
    @Value("${mongo.url.template}")
    private String urlTemplate;
    @Value("${mongoHosts}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${mongoPort}")
    private String port;
    
    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        String connectionString = urlTemplate.formatted(host, port);
        CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(new CodecRegistry[]{MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), CodecRegistries.fromProviders(new CodecProvider[]{PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()})});
        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder().applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(connectionString)).codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry).build();
        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }
}
}
```

and the test:

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
class InitInTcApplicationTests {

private static final DockerImageName dockerImageName = DockerImageName.parse("mongo:6.0.3");

static final MongoDBContainer mongoDbContainer = new MongoDBContainer(dockerImageName)
        .withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forHostPath(new ClassPathResource("src/test/resources/init/mongo-init.js").getPath()), "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js")
        .waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage("(?i).*waiting for connections.*", 2))
        .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

@DynamicPropertySource
static void mongoProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    int port = mongoDbContainer.getMappedPort(27017);
    registry.add("mongoHosts", mongoDbContainer::getHost);
    registry.add("mongoPort", () -> port);
}

@BeforeAll
static void setup() {
    mongoDbContainer.start();
}

@Autowired
InitInTcApplication.FilterService cut;

@Test
void shouldTest() {
    List<Document> dashboards = cut.getDashboardContainingOldModel();
    assertThat(dashboards).isNotEmpty();
}
}
```

In the test, I'm copying mongo-init.js file to the docker container. The scope is to seed mongo before testing.

If the mongo-init.js is empty, then the code will run as expected. If I put some content to the mongo-init.js file, then the test will fail with configuration exception.

The setup of the test was inspired by this comment: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/3066#issuecomment-1024330895

The minimum content for mongo-init.js for which the code throws configuration exception is:

```
db = new Mongo("localhost:27017").getDB("admin");
db.createUser({
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [{ role: "root", db: "admin" }]
});
```

While any content in the init script, I see the following logs:

```
12:39:31.364 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDOUT: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js
12:39:31.364 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDOUT: 
12:39:31.379 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDOUT: {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-07T09:39:31.370+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":800}}
```

And after some more logging:

```
12:39:32.454 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDERR: MongoServerError: not primary
```

From this I understand that the script is executed before the replica is registered to replica set, thus when trying to write something (from inside the init script), the replica is not primary and it fails.

Does it fails because something is wrong in the init script? What should be the content of such file in the mentioned scenario.

Comment: I expect something is wrong with the script. What happens when you use it directly through the Docker CLI instead of using Testcontainers?

Comment: @KevinWittek while this can be true, with the investigation I did this has lower probability. In the OP I've attached some logs: it can be seen that the init script is executed; at that point the replica set was not initialized. There are some more debug logs but at some point the error MongoServerError: not primary appears. What do you think about this assumption?

Comment: @SávioRaires no. I think either testcontainers maintainers or mongo ones need to change the init script of mongo to achieve this